# Geology of the San Gabriel mountains in the Angeles national forest - rock types

Tags: geology, rocks, mountains, igneous, orogeny

I'm not a geologist, I am a hiker. And after many hikes in California's Sierra Nevada and Utah's red country I figured it would be great to learn some geology and I'm just posting this question to see if I can get some clarity. Obviously, I don't know what I'm talking about and my experience is limited to reading a book, so I'd very much appreciate your opinion on what I saw on a hike today.

The hike was to strawberry peak (San Gabriel Mountains/Angeles National Forest) looking at rocks and wondering if someone can validate what I think they are :D

I was expecting to see mostly rocks like this - I think this is granite with coarse crystals - igneous rock from down deep in the earth (hand for size reference) - I believe I have this right to call this rock granite? And also that it was formed deep in the earth in a magma chamber and pushed up in whatever episode built these mountains?
[image: Is this really granite?]

This also looks like granite, is that correct? What would make the layers and straight lines in this formation? The cracks I believe are from the stresses of the rock getting uplifted and surfaced but I don't know about the lines in the rock itself

[image: Granite?]

What I was not expecting to see was stuff like this - which seems to me like sedimentary rock because of the layers and the fact that I could very easily pull off straight layers from it without any force at all:

[image: Sedimentary?]

Lastly there is what seems like a quartz vein inside this sedimentary(?) rock, is this just another layer of the rock or what type of process could inject quartz (or whatever this is) into the rock?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The layers look like a foliation to me, a feature typical of metamorphic rocks.

Comment: Ah interesting. I’ll have to read about that. I did see some layers that were in bent shapes so perhaps there was so metamorphosis going on

Comment: Yes, these can be metamorphic granitoids, but I would rather think that these are gneisses.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of rocks in San Gabriel mountain:

> Geology of the San Gabriel Mountains is mostly Mesozoic (65 to 245
> million years ago) granitic rocks, but there are also Precambrian (544
> to 4,600 million years ago) igneous and metamorphic rock complexes.
> There are also occasional Pleistocene (57.8 to 65 million years ago)
> nonmarine sedimentary deposits adjacent to the riverbed.
>
> [Source](http://ladpw.org/wmd/watershed/sg/mp/docs/eir/04.04-Geology.pdf)

Your first picture migth well be a Mesozoic granite, but also a Precambrian metamorphic granitoid.

The second one shows foliation, so it is a Precambrian metamorphic rock. Imposible to precise more with the picture.

From the third and fourth it is impossible to know what they are from a picture. They migth be Pleistocene nonmarine sedimentary deposits.

You migth wish to read some of the [publications USGS published about the zone](https://www.usgs.gov/search?keywords=san%20gabriel%20mountains).

You have some more info about the geology of the zone [here](http://www.csun.edu/science/geoscience/fieldtrips/san-gabriel-mts/geology-san-gabriels.html).